# Redirect URL to another URL

Tags: apache, redirect

I have the following page that a user can go to by where this URL exists within their email.

For example: `http://www.abc.example/yourdetails.html`

My question is, I have now been told that this whole web app is being moved to a new domain, i.e.

```
http://www.xyz.example/yourdetails.html
```

Assume there are no issues with accessing the two domains within the network (intranet), how can I redirect the user when clicking on a link in an email that is no longer the correct link to actually call the new URL:

```
http://www.abc.example/yourdetails.html
```

I basically want to ensure that even though users have old URLs in their emails, when clicking on this old URL, actually hop over to new correct URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If the site is not changing structure, you can point the xyz.com domain to abc.com in DNS.
2. I think you can configure apache, using modrewrite, to rewrite calls from the old domain to the new one. You might not be able to do this if the domains are on different servers.
3. You can edit the page at http://www.xyz.com/yourdetails.html and add a redirect header (and maybe an explanation) to redirect to the new page.

Answer (score 1):

Until you can send out new emails with the proper domain you will want to use a 301 permanent redirect on the xyz.com domain.  You can use an .htaccess file to do this.  Google for information specific to your webserver.  [This Site](http://www.squidoo.com/301) seems to have good information specific to Apache.

Answer (score 1):

By Apache's mod_rewrite module. You could create something like (on the old domain):

RewriteRule ^yourdetails.html$ http://www.xyz.com/yourdetails.html [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
window.location='http://newurl.com/page.html'
</script>
```

or even better (just one snippet for all pages)

```
<script>
window.location='http://newurl.com'+window.location.pathname
</script>
```

Comment: What if javascript isn't enabled.

Comment: Well, in that case you can do htaccess + php + html + javascript "4 in 1" redirect and email users on top of that. Something from this should work, but might be a lil overkill...

Comment: @Ash: i somehow misread the question i thought this was tagged with javascript

Comment: because it was tagged with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta tag to the top of your page on the abc domain.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=http://www.xyz.com/yourdetails.html">
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A URL by definition points to a **single** web resource, what you can do is configure your web server to map multiple URLs to the same web resource.

Please refer to [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) for more info, on how to do this on Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on an apache server, this sounds like a job for mod_rewrite.

try http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html

Answer (score 0):

in PHP:
    < ?php
    header("Location: http://www.abc.com/yourdetails.html");
    ?>

Answer (score 0):

Or using a php script on the old location:

```
<?php
    header( 'Location: http://new_page.html' ) ;
?>
```