# How to redirect main domain+sub domains to new domain

Tags: php, redirect

i need little help

i want to redirect old main domain and subdomain i created with old main domain to totaly new domain.

Like this

```
www.old-domain.com 
www.sub1.old-domain.com
www.sub2.old-domain.com
www.sub3.old-domain.com
www.sub4.old-domain.com
```

to

```
www.new-domain.com
www.sub1.new-domain.com
www.sub2.new-domain.com
www.sub3.new-domain.com
www.sub4.new-domain.com
```

think in my mind only change word ***old*** with ***new***.

kindly guide me how to achieve this

**server info**
Apache version  2.2.24
PHP version 5.3.24

Comment: It's better to let apache to the work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396929/redirect-url-to-another-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a vhost and redirect them:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.old-domain.com 
    redirect permanent / http://www.new-domain.com/
<VirtualHost>
```

Its a bit more effizient then you don't need the rewrite engine. Otherwise put an **.htaccess** file to your root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain.de
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new-domain.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

for example.

Comment: Thanks stony for replying i will tell you if it is working or not in shortly